# How to read data from database and put it into model

Tags: c#, database, mvvm, model

I'm building an application in which I store provinces and cities of a country. I have two models:

```
public class Province
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

This is the way I read province data from database:

```
public static List<Province> ReadList()
{
    var list = new List<Province>();

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Province;", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Province()
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString()
                });
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

and it works fine. My Problem is while reading the City data:

```
public static List<City> ReadList()
{
    var list = new List<City>();

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM City;", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Province()
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                    Province = ???
                });
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I know I can get the ProvinceID from reader["ProvinceID"] but I don't know Where I should get the Province data itself? Should I get it from ProvinceViewModel?

Since my view models are in a different project, how can I do that?

I really don't know where I'm wrong here?

Comment: Use a simple object mapper like [Dapper.NET](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), you will be amazed at the amount of code that you will be able to remove

Comment: I actually can't figure it out how the Dapper.NET works and it takes me some time to. could you please provide me some explanation  - even simple explanation - for me about it or about what exactly my problem is please?

Comment: @user3530012 please check my post and let me know if something is not clear. Thanks

Comment: @user3530012 does your city ID matches the province ID it belongs to?

Comment: exactly. it's the way they are stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to your problem as it is, without making use of an ORM, it would be the following:
Under the

```
var list = new List<City>();
```

Declare a list with all the provinces and fill it with the province you have - you have the way to read the data as you stated above.

```
var provinces = GetProvinces();
```

The method `GetProvinces` returns a list of all the Provinces we have.

Then in the method you read each record for the cities:

```
list.Add(new City()
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
    Province = provinces.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.ID==Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProvinceID"]));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Christos Paisios everything is clear to me except that I don't know How I must get the province list. from the provinceViewModel? because before reading the cities, I read the provinces from database and pass them to the ProvinceViewModel. I don't have any access to them from anywhere else.

Comment: Yeap, you could use the same code in order to read them . Actually, you could inject this code in a method like the GetProvinces(), I have declared above and then use it. The better it would be the data retrieval to be in one place and copy and paste the same code in different places in your application. This way your application would be more modular and more maintainable. However, you could leave this and review it, when things work as you expect. I could be more specific giving you a more detailed answer, if you let me know where you use this method -I mean the method you read the cities.

Comment: sorry I'm a little bit confused. I don't want to read the provinces from database again. I just want to access the provinces I've read from database before. and I have a problem to access to the ProvinceViewModel because I have 3 different projects for Models, ViewModels and DataAccess and if I add a reference from ViewModels to the DataAccess, I get the circular dependency error. I read the cities and provinces in the dataaccess layer.

Comment: ok, Since you have layered your application, you can use the method of your data access layer, which retrieves the provinces. If you are not using caching, then you have to request the data from the database each time you want them. Does this make sense or not?

Comment: Absolutely. Now I think I have to know about how I should implement a caching system. Is there any references out there?

Comment: Sure thing. There are plenty of tutorials on this topic. I would suggest you take a look at the official site of asp.net www.asp.net and then do some googling in case of not finding anything interesting there.